# Invalid (static) method with Invoke-CimMethod

Tags: powershell, methods, wmi

I'm trying to set a value with the PowerShell cmdled Invoke-CimMethod, but I'm getting an error "Invalid method" and i'm at a bit of a loss at the moment. This is my code

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled=1' -MethodName EnableWINS -Arguments @{WINSEnableLMHostsLookup=[Boolean]$false}
```

According to the documentation, the argument "WINSEnableLMHostsLookup" should be a bool, but for some reason it just doesn't work this way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/settcpipnetbios-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration

Can anyone share some insights?

Comment: Not sure, but I think method EnableWINS needs at least two parameters: `-Arguments @{DNSEnabledForWINSResolution = $false; WINSEnableLMHostsLookup = $false}`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/enablewins-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration)

Comment: Hi Theo, Yeah I've noticed that right after my post. Even after using your suggestion I'm getting the same "Invalid Method".

Comment: Funny thing is.... If I do it like this it works:

$NicClass = [wmiclass]"Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
$NicClass.EnableWINS($false,$false)

I would really like to understand the "Why" behind it.

Comment: OK, so apparently this method cannot handle named parameters and wants the values only (in order). I couldn't test myself..

Comment: So that means I would use @{$false,$false} ?

Comment: I have no idea if that works. I would use the syntax you already tested out: `$NicClass = [wmiclass]"Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" $NicClass.EnableWINS($false,$false)`

Comment: I understand.... however I would like to udnerstand why it works like that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a static method, like in any programming language, not an instance method.  You don't need to run some kind of constructor first, or find an existing object.  It sets a default.  Use -classname with static methods.  It's not the most user friendly or well documented.

```
Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Arguments @{WINSEnableLMHostsLookup=$false} -MethodName EnableWINS

# or arguments by position
Invoke-CimMethod Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration @{WINSEnableLMHostsLookup=$false} EnableWINS
```

Old way with the wmiclass type accelerator:

```
$NicClass = [wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration'
$NicClass.EnableWINS($false, $false)
```

CIM is self-documenting if you really want to dig into it.  The qualifiers will say whether a method is static.

```
get-cimclass Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | % cimclassmethods | 
  select name,qualifiers

Name       Qualifiers
----       ----------
EnableWINS {Implemented, MappingStrings, Static, ValueMap}
```

Hmm, what is "CQL"?

Comment: CQL = CIM Query Language - see http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0202_1.0.0.pdf

Comment: @mklement0 How is it different from WQL?

Comment: Good question; WQL (WMI Query Language, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) is supposedly an _implementation_ of CQL (the linked doc makes no mention of that) - I don't know why _both_ are being offered via `-QueryDialect`, and how they differ.

Comment: Briliant! Thank you so much, this is the answer I was looking for,

Comment: Done! And thanks again, really appreciate you taking the time to explain.